# Broken Airflow DAG: No Module Found From Docker Requirement Instillation

Tags: airflow, python-import, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am facing an issue where my DAG isn't importing into Airflow due to a "ModuleNotFoundError: No Module Name *package*" error.

The provider throwing the error shows in the Airflow UI and works if I import it inside of a Python Operator. I am installing the provider via a requirements file in a Docker Image which also shows correct instillation and show's it's installed in site packages. I am running via a Celery executor on Kubernetes. Could this have something to do with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This occurred due to several Kubernetes pods not being re-built. This caused my scheduler to not have the required packages which caused the import errors. I manually restarted those nodes and re-built it from the last Docker file and everything ran smoothly.